# Can't see Android graphical layout

Tags: android, layout, eclipse-plugin

I have started a new Android empty project.
Where can i find the graphical layout switch button ?

I have Eclipse Java EE and didn't installed any ADT plug-ins
because i am guessing they are already installed.

Do i need to put initial code before i'll be able to use it?
i read that i need to open the XML file to use the graphical layout,
the only xml file that i found is the manifest.
and accessing this file didn't get any result.

thanks,
Rami

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will find the layout xml files in /res/layout/*.xml.

These are the files that when opened will have a graphical editor.

If there aren't any then you can make one by using the new XML wizard.